# Error bars in a logarithmic scale plot with Python

Tags: python, graph

I'm working on a long code that produces the following [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTcP5.jpg).

The problem is that the error bars change their length because of the logarithmic scale, and I would like all of them to appear equal to each other, that is, to have a fixed length. Is there any way to do this easily with Python?

**Edit:** Here is part of the code, where I generate the error bars.

```
faztec=[11.4,11.4,7.1,7.7,6.8,6.9,6.2,7.5,5.5,4.0,3.5,3.2,2.9,2.9]
flaboca=[9.8,7.3,6.8,8.2,6.8,8.1,6.7,11.0,10.6,4.2,7.0,7.1,5.0,5.3]

err1 = [1.5,1.5,1.7,1.8,1.4,1.5,1.7,3.0,2.7,1.4,1.9,1.9,1.4,1.8]
err2 = [0.7,0.7,0.7,0.8,0.7,0.7,0.7,0.9,0.7,0.7,0.7,0.7,0.7,0.7]

newErr1x = []
newErr1y = []

for i in range(0, len(y)):
    x1 = x[i]
    y1 = (flaboca[i]-err1[i])/(faztec[i]+err2[i])
    x2 = x[i]
    y2 = (flaboca[i]+err1[i])/(faztec[i]-err2[i])
    pl.plot([x1, x2], [y1, y2])
    correction = False
    # when end of segment is near 0, we must change it (because of logx)
    if x2 < endBarLen:
        x2 = 0.03
        endBarLen = endBarLen / 10
        correction = True
    pl.plot([x1+endBarLen, x2-endBarLen], [y1, y1], '-k')
    pl.plot([x1+endBarLen, x2-endBarLen], [y2, y2], '-k')
    if correction:
        correction = False
        endBarLen = endBarLen*10
pl.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are likely passing in an array as your error, but instead you should pass in the same value for every error bar if you wish for them to be the same length. It appears as if your y axis is not log-scale - if you wish to transform your values from log-space to linear space, you could take the exponent or log of your error data to adjust it accordingly. I would be able to provide a more specific answer if given more specific information

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've edited my question to add part of the code I'm using.